# Sending email from Exchange & Notes

Tags: email-server, exchange-2013, newsletters, email

We have a domain, contoso.com, which is running under Lotus Domino 9.
Under said domain we have accounts like alexander@contoso.com or info@contoso.com, and we can send and receive eMail with Lotus Notes and iNotes. This domain has an MX record.

Furthermore, we have a subdomain, intra.contoso.com, which is intranet-only (not in public DNS) and running under a developer license of Exchange. As of now, the Exchange server cannot send email to external servers (I guess I have to configure that somehow?).

Now I want to biweekly send personalized and localized newsletters to all people from a list growing in a MSSQL database table. The newsletters From address shall be info@contoso.com

Since I am a C# developer, I thought to write a small program that uses EWS to create and send the eMails.

I would have to configure Exchange server to send eMails to the net, and I would require eMails sent from Exchange to use a different eMail domain. How can I achieve that?

But then, perhaps there is a better way to send out newsletters with one click?

Comment: Maintaining Exchange just to send some newsletters is pretty heavyweight. Hopefully you're using it for more than that. There are tons of other ways you could send email (`blat.exe`, etc) in lieu of Exchange.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the newsletters will mostly contain sth like `a new/updated version of <some self-developed outlook plugin> is available`... for development/testing of these plugins we need Exchange, but an island solution was completely sufficient.